# Wireshark, using "Decode as", BACnet is missing as a choice

Tags: wireshark

I'm trying to decode BACnet traffic that was sent on a non-standard port.  It looks like I should be able to click "decode as" and choose BACnet or BACapp, but they don't appear in the selection list.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

**Instructions**

- Start Wireshark
- Load or capture some BACnet packets on a non standard port
- From the “Analyse” menu select “Decode as”
- Select the non default BACnet IP udp port number in the drop down box.
- Select “BVLC” from the right hand menu. *Note: “BVLC” stands for “BACnet Virtual Link Control” and is the header to all BACnet IP messages.*
- Click OK

From: http://www.chipkin.com/using-wireshark-to-decode-bacnet-traffic-on-non-standard-ports/